# How to trigger onChange manually in dropdown when values are pre-populated on page load in React

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

The React Form works fine when values are clicked in Dropdown which triggers the onChange function. However, I am trying to pre-populate the dropdown values on page load (By establishing dependencies among dropdowns) and this is where I ran into issues where the onChange function didn't pick the values if it was not modified manually.

I tried calling it manually using the below code snippet, but the onChange didn't get triggered.

```
        var element = document.getElementById("non_prod_env_id_textbox");
        var event = new Event('change');
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Here's my full code.

```
import "./App.css";
import image from "./image/description.png";
import { Container, Button, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Amplify from "aws-amplify";
import { API } from "aws-amplify";

import { withAuthenticator, SignIn, ConfirmSignIn, Greetings, VerifyContact } from 'aws-amplify-react';
import MyTheme from "./components/AmplifyTheme";

import awsExports from "./aws-exports";
Amplify.configure(awsExports);

async function addData() {  
  const data = {
    body: {
      account_id: formState.account_id,
      app_id: formState.app_id,
      customer_id: formState.customer_id,
      customer_name: formState.customer_name,
      non_prod_environment_name: formState.non_prod_environment_name,
      non_prod_env_id: formState.non_prod_env_id,
      project_key: formState.project_key,
      parent_ou_id: formState.parent_ou_id,
      working_directory: formState.working_directory,
      request_status: "Pending",
    },
  };

  console.log(data);
  const apiData = await API.post("onboardapi", "/items", data);
  console.log({ apiData });
  alert("Request Submitted");
}

const formState = {
  account_id: "",
  app_id: "",
  message: "",
  customer_id: "",
  customer_name: "",
  non_prod_environment_name: "",
  non_prod_env_id: "",
  project_key: "",
  parent_ou_id: "",
  working_directory: "",
  request_status: "",
};

function updateFormState(key, value) {  
  formState[key] = value;
  if(document.getElementById("non_prod_environment_name_dropdown").value==='Other')
    {
        document.getElementById("non_prod_environment_name_textbox").disabled=false;

    }

  else if (document.getElementById("non_prod_environment_name_dropdown").value === 'Development')
    {
        document.getElementById("non_prod_env_id_textbox").value ='dev'; 
        var element = document.getElementById("non_prod_env_id_textbox");
        var event = new Event('change');
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
  else if (document.getElementById("non_prod_environment_name_dropdown").value === 'Production')
    {
        document.getElementById("non_prod_env_id_textbox").value ='prd'; 
    }
  else if (document.getElementById("non_prod_environment_name_dropdown").value === 'Test')
    {
        document.getElementById("non_prod_env_id_textbox").value ='uat'; 
    }    
  else{
        document.getElementById("non_prod_environment_name_textbox").disabled=true;
      }
  
}


function App() {
  const [working_directory] = useState();
  const [parent_ou_id] = useState();
  const [project_key] = useState();
  const [non_prod_env_id] = useState();
  const [non_prod_environment_name] = useState();

  return (
    <Container>
      <div className="Title">
        <div className="Title-Subtitle">
          {" "}
          <h1>Self Service Account Onboarding</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h3>Account Onboard Request Parameters</h3>
        <img src={image} alt="Image" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Account Onboard Request Form</h3>
        <br />
        <Form>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>account_id</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              placeholder="account_id"
              onChange={(e) => updateFormState("account_id", e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>app_id</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              placeholder="app_id"
              onChange={(e) => updateFormState("app_id", e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>customer_id</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              placeholder="customer_id"
              onChange={(e) => updateFormState("customer_id", e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>customer_name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              placeholder="customer_name"
              onChange={(e) => updateFormState("customer_name", e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>non_prod_environment_name</Form.Label>
            <select
              className="custom-select"
              id="non_prod_environment_name_dropdown"
              value={non_prod_environment_name}
              onChange={(e) =>
                updateFormState("non_prod_environment_name", e.target.value)
              }
            >
              <option value="Production">Default(Production)</option>
              <option value="Production">Production</option>
              <option value="Development">Development</option>
              <option value="Test">Test</option>
              <option value="Other">Other / Enter manually</option>
            </select>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>non_prod_environment_name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              placeholder="non_prod_environment_name enter manually"
              id="non_prod_environment_name_textbox"
              disabled="disabled"
              onChange={(e) => updateFormState("non_prod_environment_name", e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>non_prod_env_id</Form.Label>
            <select
              className="custom-select"
              id="non_prod_env_id_textbox"
              value={non_prod_env_id}
              onChange={(e) =>
                updateFormState("non_prod_env_id", e.target.value)
              }
            >
              <option value="prd">Default(prd)</option>
              <option value="dev">dev</option>
              <option value="prd">prd</option>
              <option value="uat">uat</option>
            </select>
          </Form.Group>

           <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>project_key</Form.Label>
            <select
              className="custom-select"
              value={project_key}
              onChange={(e) => updateFormState("project_key", e.target.value)}
            >
              <option value="CUS">Default(CUS)</option>
              <option value="CUS">CUS</option>
              <option value="LAB">LAB</option>
            </select>
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>parent_ou_id</Form.Label>
            <select
              className="custom-select"
              value={parent_ou_id}
              onChange={(e) => updateFormState("parent_ou_id", e.target.value)}
            >
              <option value="r-xx1">Default(r-xx1)</option>
              <option value="r-xx2">r-mvhx (Production Org)</option>
              <option value="r-xx3">r-wmno (Test Org)</option>
            </select>
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>working_directory</Form.Label>
            <select
              className="custom-select"
              value={working_directory}
              onChange={(e) =>
                updateFormState("working_directory", e.target.value)
              }
            >
              <option value='"uat"'>"uat"</option>
              <option value='"dev"'>"dev"</option>
              <option value='"prd"'>"prd"</option>
            </select>
          </Form.Group>

          <Button onClick={addData}>Submit Request</Button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}

// export default App;

export default withAuthenticator(App, false, [  //Comment this when testing locally
  <Greetings />,
  <SignIn />,
  <ConfirmSignIn />,
  <VerifyContact />,
], null, MyTheme)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set default value in useState function.
Just pass value to it like below

const [non_prod_env_id] = useState(‘prd’);

You don't need to pass event to DOM manually, React will automatically populate data to DOM elements.
In fact, it is the whole points of using UI framework like React.

You seemingly have very good understand about vanilla JS, but some how have a wrong start with React.
I recommend you to read through the React getting started tutorial one more times to regain the overview of the framework. This will save you a-lot of time.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @datlt - I however later figured this issue by manually updating Form state and it worked.

```
  else if (document.getElementById("non_prod_environment_name_dropdown").value === 'Development')
{
    document.getElementById("non_prod_env_id_textbox").value ='dev'; 
    element = document.getElementById("non_prod_env_id_textbox");
    formState["non_prod_env_id"] = element.value;
}
```